# Duplicated results following a search?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

I did a search for "VHF", and got the following result twice in the results:-

- [How many VHF system can be in MEL for an A340?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11196/how-many-vhf-system-can-be-in-mel-for-an-a340)

I'm assuming this is because the text "VHF" is in both the question in answer.

Shouldn't the results returned be distinct?

Screen-dump of search:

[image]

Comment: The first result is the question (starts with Q) and the last one is an answer to that question (starts with an A). You can specify just questions, for example, by adding `is:question` to your query.

Comment: @fooot Interesting to know (result type filtering); thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You search for just "VHF" finds all posts, not just questions or answers that match.  The results are not duplicate, one is a question and one is an answer (that happens to be for the question).  These are different posts, so the search finds them both.

If you want to restrict your search to questions or answers, you can add constraints to your search query.

For example, searching for `VHF is:question` will restrict your search results to just posts that are questions.